# asp.net Concatenate files

Tags: asp.net, wcf, file, rest, concatenation

In my program, i split a file into multiple files and sent it to a WCF rest service which then joins it back to one file. After concatenate, the file size is more than the size of the file sent.

Following is the code to concatenate:

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, string.Concat(guid, "*"),SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        StreamReader fileReader;
        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(path + newGuid);
        for (Int64 count = 0; count < files.Length; count++)
        {
            fileReader = new StreamReader(string.Concat(path,guid, count));
            fileWriter.Write(fileReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        fileWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Are you doing this to get around the WCF 64K message size issue?  Why would you split files and rejoin them?  Seems like a waste of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Are your dealing with only text files because both `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` are meant to be used only for text files and not binary files.

Further, this line `fileWriter.Write(fileReader.);` appears to be wrong. It should be something like

```
fileWriter.Write(fileReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Of course, if your file size is too large, you should be doing reading/writing in chunks or line by line basis.

Comment: No. This is what i was using. Missed that code. It gives me a file whose size is more then the splitted files.

Comment: @Ankit, why don't you go over the file content and decide what's getting added extra? You can even concat split files manually and use any diff tool!